# DolphinDB error: A metric shouldn't be a constant in reactive state engine

Tags: constants, state, metrics, reactive, dolphindb

My script is

```
share streamTable(1:0, `date`time`sym`market`price`qty, [DATE, TIME, SYMBOL, CHAR, DOUBLE, INT]) as trade
outputTable = table(100:0, `date`sym`factor1`flag, [DATE, STRING, DOUBLE, INT])
engine = createReactiveStateEngine(name="test", metrics=[<mavg(price, 3)>, <1>], dummyTable=trade, outputTable=outputTable, keyColumn=["date","sym"], filter=<date between 2012.01.01 : 2012.01.03>, keepOrder=true)
```

It throws A metric shouldn't be a constant. How to pass a constant to the metircs?

Answer (score 0):

Try using <1*1> instead.